# Value changing error of the array's first element when passed to a method in C

Tags: c, arrays, function

I have created one array, got input from the user, and passed that array into a method.
After passing it, the value of first element changes and I can't understand why and how.

For instance:

I enter 55 1 2 6 7 5 4 0  displays 70 1 2 6 7 5 4.

Similarly,  121 5 6 1 2 0 displays 26227 5 6 1 2.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int sequence[100];
    int i;
    int sequenceSize =0;

    for(i =0; i < 100; i++){
        scanf("%d",&sequence[i]);
        if(sequence[i] == 0){
            break;
        }
        sequenceSize++;         
    }
    method(sequence, sequenceSize);
    return 0;
 }

 void method( int A[] , int sequenceSize){
      int M;
      printf("This is the array \n");
      for(M = 0; M < sequenceSize; M++){
          printf("%d ", A[M]);
      }
 }
```

Comment: You need to provide a prototype for `method`. Do `void method( int A[] , int sequenceSize);` just above `main()`. Otherwise, I can't see how the problem you see can happen.

Comment: Hmm..  I got nuthin'. There are no errors/warnings?  Debugger?

Comment: Cannot reproduce either targeting `i686-w64-mingw32`, even without the prototype.

Comment: Try printing the array *before* you call `method`. Check what exactly you have in the array. The function is not changing the contents of the array in any way.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's a problem of your IDE. Clean your project before running.
You can test your program here
https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler